# User friendly timezone names from tz database format

Tags: timezone

I have timezones in the following array format:

```
'America/New_York' => '(GMT-05:00) Eastern Time (US & Canada)',
'Europe/Lisbon' => '(GMT) Greenwich Mean Time : Lisbon',
```

etc.

How do I go about displaying a user-friendly summer/daylight savings time dependent timezone identifier to the user?

For example, displaying the time now in New York would append "(EDT)" to the time, which would make sense for local users. I want to avoid having to display ((GMT-05:00) Eastern Time (US & Canada)) or just (GMT-05:00), which isn't strictly accurate all year round.

Ideally then, is there a web service/database that can take a tz string in the format "America/New_York", and a timestamp as paramters and return the abbreviation in the formats [here](http://www.timeanddate.com/library/abbreviations/timezones/)?

Comment: Good question. When working on a javascript timezone detection script (jsTimezoneDetect @ bitbucket) I was thinking about including that but abandoned the effort. There were just too many conventions and ambiguities to my taste.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`strftime`'s `%Z` format specifier gives you this abbreviation. You didn't say what programming language you are using, but most programming languages give you access to `strftime` in one way or another.

Python:

```
import pytz
from datetime import datetime

here = pytz.timezone('Asia/Tokyo')
print here.localize(datetime.utcnow()).strftime("%Z")

there = pytz.timezone('America/Montreal')
print there.localize(datetime.utcnow()).strftime("%Z")
```

PHP:

```
date_default_timezone_set("Asia/Tokyo");
echo strftime("%Z");

date_default_timezone_set("America/Montreal");
echo strftime("%Z");
```